# How can i get only a list of video id from youtube api?

Tags: python, api, youtube

so far i am trying to wrap my head around this code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
    
   

    request = youtube.search().list(
        part="id",
        maxResults=25,
        q="Askreddit"
    )
    response = request.execute()
    print(response[1]['items']['id']['videoId'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but i am not really understanding how to access the single part i want, since it gives me KeyError1
If i just ask for print(response) it shows me a really unconfortable wall of text, while my final goal it would be to output an automatic formatted txt file where every id retrieved gets concatenated to the standard https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=  so that the script, once run, will give me a txt file filled with video links directly accessible.

I am still learning and i am pretty much at an entry-level skill but i'm stuck on this since a week ago.

Comment: I am not keen on Google's libraries, I prefer to directly fetch and treat the JSON from https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id&maxResults=25&q=Askreddit&key=API_KEY maybe how I do may interest you.

Comment: I think it should be: `response['items'][0]['id']['videoId']`. This will return the first search result. For bring all videoIds, you have to use `nextPageToken` - for bring the next batch of results in the next page and change the code something like: `for video in response['items']: print("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video['id']['videoId'])`...